# building a responsive table using javascript

Tags: javascript

After completing  Javascript/jQuery course using Jon Duckets book, I decided to try out a project which was to create a table in the HTML section and then add the table rows and table dynamically using javascript. I included new text fields in the html section with an add Button, such that when clicked, the add button appends the newly input fields into the table. I was able to do this tho but through out the weekend, I have been trying to include an Edit/Delete button such that when clicked, edits or deletes the table row which was clicked but I haven't been making any positive Headway since on Saturday and I am visibly tired and frustrated. PLEASE I NEED HELP.

```js
let $next = $('#nextInfo');
$next.hide();

$('#Amor').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $next = $('#nextInfo');
  $next.fadeIn(500);
})

function formClear() {
  $('#name').val('');
  $('#sex').val('');
  $('#dob').val('');
  $('#state').val('');
  $('#class').val('');
}

function addTable() {
  let $nam = $('#name').val();
  let $sex = $('#sex').val();
  let $dob = $('#dob').val();
  let $state = $('#state').val();
  let $class = $('#class').val();
  let $next = $('#nextInfo');
  let $add = $('#Add');

  $('table tbody').append(
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" +
    "<button type='button' " + 'id="edbutt" + >' +
    "Edit" +
    "</button>" +
    "</td>" +
    '<td>' + $nam + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + $sex + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + $class + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + $dob + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + $state + '</td>' +
    "<td>" +
    "<button type='button' " + 'id="debutt" + >' +
    "Delete" +
    "</button>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>");

  formClear();
  $next.fadeOut(500);
};

let Add = document.getElementById('Add');
Add.addEventListener('click', addTable);
```

```css
#nextInfo {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#upper {
  background: rgb(85, 109, 204);
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 498px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 30px;
}

.mu {
  margin-left: -325px;
}

.me {
  margin-left: -320px;
}

#Add {
  height: 35px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -300px;
}

#debutt {
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid rgb(39, 39, 180);
  color: #fff;
}

#debutt:hover {
  background: rgb(136, 136, 212);
}

#edbutt {
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid rgb(39, 39, 180);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Miracle's Assignment</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade|Covered+By+Your+Grace" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mir7.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">


    <table id="personalDetails" class="table table-bordered
                            table-condensed table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Edit</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Sex</th>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>DoB</th>
          <th>State</th>
          <th>Delete</th>

        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="" id="Amor">Add More</a></td>
          <td>Gbambor Jnr</td>
          <td>Male</td>
          <td>SS5</td>
          <td>1994</td>
          <td>Anambra</td>
          <td id="del">
            <a href=""><img src="delete.png" height="25px"></a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <form id="newItem">

      <div id="nextInfo">


        <b><div id="upper">Table Data</div></b>
        <br><b><p class="me" > Name</p><input type="text" id="name"> </b>
        <br><b><p class="mu" >Sex</p><input type="text" id="sex"> </b>
        <br><b><p class="mu" >DOB</p><input type="text" id="dob"> </b>
        <br><b><p class="me" >Class</p><input type="text" id="class"></b>
        <br><b><p class="me" >State</p><input type="text" id="state"></b>
        <p><input type="button" value="Add" id="Add" class="btn btn-primary"></p>


      </div>

  </div>
  </div>

  </form>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mir7.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried so many codes and deleted them at the end when they weren't working. I can't even remeber some of the codes I tried. Please someone fix the Edit and delete Button for me(in a way for a beginner to easily understand) so that when clicked edits/deletes the row that was clicked. THANK YOU

Comment: Your code, in the snippet, produces the error: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $next is not defined"`

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Wrapping code and writing "fix my code, I've tried many things, but now I'm tired and frustrated" is not a good description of issue

Comment: hello David the $next up above is the same I defined inside the function . that is $next = $('#nextInfo')

Comment: Hey Barbsan, thank you for the corrections, I'm relatively new here, and look to improve. I have just read through the link you posted above and will sure improve when I'm asking my next and subsequent questions. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Link https://plnkr.co/edit/rZA05SEkLB8aPyTMdQSG?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Miracle's Assignment</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee|Bungee+Shade|Covered+By+Your+Grace" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mir7.css"> -->
        <style>
        #nextInfo {
    border:1px blue solid;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius:5px;
  }

  #upper{
      background: rgb(85, 109, 204);
      height:50px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      color:#fff;
      width: 498px;
      padding-top:10px;
  }

  input{
      width: 350px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      height: 30px;
  }


  .mu{
      margin-left: -325px;
  }

  .me{
      margin-left: -320px;
  }

  #Add{
      height:35px;
      width:75px;
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-left: -300px;


  }

  #debutt{
      background: blue;
      border:1px solid rgb(39, 39, 180);
      color:#fff;
  }

  #debutt:hover{
      background: rgb(136, 136, 212);
  }

  #edbutt{
    background: blue;
    border:1px solid rgb(39, 39, 180);
    color:#fff;
}
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container" >


                        <table id="personalDetails" class="table table-bordered
                        table-condensed table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th ><a href="javascript:void(o)" id="Amor">Add More</a></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Sex</th>
                                    <th>Class</th>
                                    <th>DoB</th>
                                    <th>State</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>

                                </tr>

                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr id="rowid">
                                    <td><button id="edbutt" onclick="editRow('rowid')">Edit</button></td>
                                    <td id="tname">Gbambor Jnr</td>
                                    <td id="tsex">Male</td>
                                    <td id="tclass">SS5</td>
                                    <td id="tdob">1994</td>
                                    <td id="tstate">Anambra</td>
                                    <td><button id="debutt" onclick="deleteRow('rowid')">delete</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                         </table>

                    <form id="newItem">

                         <div id="nextInfo" >


                            <b><div id="upper">Table Data</div></b>
                        <br><b><p class="me" > Name</p><input type="text" id="name"> </b>
                        <br><b><p class="mu" >Sex</p><input type="text" id="sex"> </b>
                        <br><b><p class="mu" >DOB</p><input type="text" id="dob"> </b>
                        <br><b><p class="me" >Class</p><input type="text" id="class"></b>
                        <br><b><p class="me" >State</p><input type="text" id="state"></b>
                        <p><input  type="button" value="Add" id="Add" class="btn btn-primary"></p> 


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
//$next.hide();

$('#Amor').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let $next = $('#nextInfo');
    $next.find('#Add').val('Add');
    $next.fadeIn(500);
})
let editRowId;
function formClear(){
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#sex').val('');
    $('#dob').val('');
    $('#state').val('');
    $('#class').val('');
}
function deleteRow(id){
    var row= $('#'+id);
    $('table tbody tr#'+id).remove();
}
function editRow(id){
    editRowId = id;
    let $next = $('#nextInfo');
    $next.find('#Add').val('Edit');
    $next.fadeIn(500);
     var row= $('#'+id);
     $next.find('#name').val(row.find('#tname').html())
     $next.find('#sex').val(row.find('#tsex').html())
     $next.find('#dob').val(row.find('#tdob').html())
     $next.find('#state').val(row.find('#tstate').html())
     $next.find('#class').val(row.find('#tclass').html())
}

function addTable(){
        let $id = Date.now();
        let $nam =$('#name').val();
        let $sex =$('#sex').val();
        let $dob =$('#dob').val();
        let $state =$('#state').val();
        let $class =$('#class').val();
        let $next = $('#nextInfo');
        let $add =$('#Add');
    if($next.find('#Add').val()==='Edit' && editRowId){
        $('#'+editRowId).find('#tname').text($nam);
        $('#'+editRowId).find('#tsex').text($sex);
        $('#'+editRowId).find('#tdob').text($dob);
        $('#'+editRowId).find('#tstate').text($state);
        $('#'+editRowId).find('#tclass').text($class);
        editRowId = null;
    }else{
        $('table tbody').append(
           "<tr id="+$id+">"+
               "<td><button onclick=editRow("+$id+") type=button id=edbutt>Edit</button> </td>" +
                   '<td id=tname>'+ $nam+'</td>'+
                   '<td id=tsex>'+ $sex +'</td>'+
                   '<td id=tclass>'+  $class+'</td>'+ 
                   '<td id=tdob>'+ $dob+'</td>'+ 
                   '<td id=tstate>'+ $state +'</td>'+
                   "<td>" +
                   "<button onclick=deleteRow("+$id+") type=button id=debutt >Delete</button>" +
                 "</td>" +
           "</tr>");
    }
         $next.fadeOut(500);
         formClear();
};
let Add =document.getElementById('Add');
Add.addEventListener('click', addTable);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ohh MY !!!!!!!!THANKS A MILLION VIRENDER ..... tho i don't understand the concepts which was (i) setting $id= Date.now(); and making it to replace rowId in the edit and delete sections. i will really appreciate if you can explain that .... regardless I'm so happy you came through for me with the solution. Bless you

Comment: Hi Gbambor, `$id= Date.now()` is to generate a unique id for every row, 'rowId' i gave for the staic row only, if you want you can also replace that with Date.now(), the reason behind to give a unique id for every row is that we can know which row we are editing or deleting. as same id I am passing in delete and edit function.

Comment: Virender this was very useful. THANK YOU A MILLION